# Flutter app stuck in black screen when opening in some android devices

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I recently uploaded my first Flutter app to the Play Store. Some Android users have reported that the app shows a black screen when launching the app and stays there, it doesn't load or show the app content. I don't know if it can be related or just a coincidence, but all 3 of them have a Samsung phone with Android 12, but I have tried it on my Samsung with Android 12 and works fine.
I tried updating the flutter version and the plugins but they are still getting this black screen and the app doesn't show.
My `minSdkVersion = 21`, `targetSdkVersion = 30` and `complieSdkVersion = 33`.
Does anybody have any idea on what could be the cause for that? I'm completely lost.
Thanks!

Comment: Is the app of yours been made specifically for mobile devices? Are you using any deprecated packages? What is your minSDKVersion ?

Comment: @Arijeet yes, it's only for mobile devices. I'm not using deprecated packages and my minSDKVersion is 21, targetSdkVersion = 30, and complieSdkVersion = 33

Comment: My users have similar experiences, I have to set minSdkVersion to 19 for them.